# Asp Classic put the Sub in the function... Can i?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

why now return ....Syntax error

Can i put the Sub rutine in the function? Or better way for this?!

```
Function SumerizePlanArrays(f_String, f_Type)

   Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   Sub Add(s)
       weight = Split(s,"$")(0)
       values = Split(s,"$")(1)
       pipes = Split(values, "|")
       For Each line In pipes
           val = Split(line, ",")
           if f_Type = 1 then
               dic(val(1)) = (dic(val(1))*weight/100) + CInt(val(2))
           elseif f_Type = 2 then
               dic(val(1)) = dic(val(1)) + CInt(val(2))
           end if
       Next
   End Sub

   arrString = Split(f_String,"#")
   For i = 0 to UBound(arrString)
       'wei = Split(arrString(i),"$")(0)
       Add arrString(i)
   Next

   Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
   For Each key In dic.Keys
       a.Add "0," & key & "," & dic(key)
   Next
   a.Sort
   result = Join(a.ToArray, "|")

   SumerizePlanArrays = result

End Function
```

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ea'
>
> Syntax error
>
> /inc_func_projects.asp, line 2592
>
> Sub Add(s)
>   ^

Comment: Errr... Why?  A function is meant to return a value, whereas a Sub does not, but both are distinct blocks of code with a specific purpose.

Comment: You can also work with a Class, then it can have its own methods.

Comment: You can "put" a function or a sub into another one creating it dynamically within the parent with the code e. g. `Execute "Sub Message(x): MsgBox x: End Sub"`, this sub doesn't appear in global scope, it could be called within the parent only, and it lives until the parent end.
But this trick won't give you the opportunities, such closures in JavaScript, since the nested sub doesn't have an access to the parent's scope, it works only in global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - you can't put a sub within a function, except in JavaScript or in the server side version called JScript.  VBScript and JScript are two completely different languages, however.

You should be doing this...

```
Function SumerizePlanArrays(f_String, f_Type)

   Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   arrString = Split(f_String,"#")
   For i = 0 to UBound(arrString)
       'NOTE: Updated the call to reflect comment by sadrasjd...
       Add arrString(i, f_Type, dic)
   Next

   Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
   For Each key In dic.Keys
       a.Add "0," & key & "," & dic(key)
   Next
   a.Sort
   result = Join(a.ToArray, "|")

   SumerizePlanArrays = result

End Function

Sub Add(s, type, dic)
    'NOTE: ^Updated the parameters to reflect comment by sadrasjd^
    weight = Split(s,"$")(0)
    values = Split(s,"$")(1)
    pipes = Split(values, "|")
    For Each line In pipes
        val = Split(line, ",")
        if type = 1 then
            dic(val(1)) = (dic(val(1))*weight/100) + CInt(val(2))
        elseif type = 2 then
            dic(val(1)) = dic(val(1)) + CInt(val(2))
        end if
    Next
End Sub
```

NOTE: Updated the call to reflect the suggestion made by *sadrasjd*.

Comment: This is just the solution to the question you posted. If you want me to take a look at the logic behind the code I can.   There are a few changes I would make.

Comment: @Paul Yeah like using a plain old `Array()` for starters... `Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")` yuck!

Comment: @Lankymart: Hehe! You've got to start somewhere...  There first two lines in the sub worry me a little.  Also, `Option Explicit` isn't set.

Comment: @sadrasjd: You should really turn [`Option Explicit`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/14168) on; it will save you a lot of pain later.

Comment: @Paul, actually a sub can be "put" within a function. Dynamically.

Comment: @Paul, please scroll up to my comment for the question.

Comment: @Paul,@omegastripes,@Lankymart,Thanks to all who participated

Comment: @omegastripes: Oh! God!  That's hideous!

Comment: @sadrasjd: No probs.  Good luck :o)